# Finding index of specific values in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning

In example matrix

```
a1=[1;1;1;2;2];
b1=[1;1;2;2;2];
```

Can I compare `a1` and `b1` matrix, which is equal  in the case of 1 value in `a1` matrix?

target matrix

```
c1=[1,1,0,0,0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a logical array by using the `==` operator. Based on your question, I assume you want where `a1` and `b1` are both equal to 1. We can use the and (`&`) operator to combine the two logical arrays created by `a1 == 1` and `b1 == 1`.

```
c1 = a1 == 1 & b1 == 1;
%   1   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and operator &

```
a1 == 1 & b1 == 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad if it can help